# Request Param truncated

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am just learning to build webapps using express, angular and mongoose.

My angular controller passes on the url "`/contact/54a153243aac91fc28605b0b`" The last bit being the _id of the record in my mongo database.

on the server side, I prepend the url with /api, so that the effective url is "`/api/contact/54a153243aac91fc28605b0b`"

When I am accessing the parameter on the server side, I expect to get "54a153243aac91fc28605b0b" as req.param.id, but i am just getting "54".

Interestingly if I type in the following on the address bar of the browser directly, I am able to get the full ID. I.e. if I type "`http://localhost:3000/api/contact/54a153243aac91fc28605b0b`" In this case, I am also getting the expected JSON response.

I am struggling to debug this. Any hints. Please help.

Comment: How do you prepend the url?

Comment: can you output all the params? also, check in the console what data you're sending.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I prepend the URL with the statement 'app.use('/api',api)'

Comment: @SoluableNonagon i logging all the params, when i log the _id I am getting just "54" instead of "54a153243aac91fc28605b0b"

Comment: Well, now you have to trace it back to the origin, to see where it changes from the long key to the short key... then you should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In express `app.use` method does not prepend anything to the url. It is used to apply middleware for appropriate url.

So, if you have `app.use('/api',api)`, then you should always access it with the url that starts with `/api`.

That's why your angular code is not working as expected. You should have the full url including the `/api` part in it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and see whats going wrong. But the req.originalUrl logs the following

/api/contact/54 instead of 
/api/contact/54a153243aac91fc28605b0b

so, I have managed to get the URL right, but the parameter is truncated. 


I have tried passing a Decimal, instead of a HEx and that link is working. I am debugging and will update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the param was truncated. IN a certain place in my code I was doing a 'parseInt($routeParams.id, 10)' which was causing the Hex id to be truncated to a decimal.

Than you for the support!

~Kishan